# Al intentar eliminar un archivo, se lanza la excepción System.IO.IOException: El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo

Tags: c#

Me manda este error

> System.IO.IOException: 'El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'C:\Users\kareem\OneDrive - UNIVERSIDAD NACIONAL AUTÓNOMA DE MÉXICO\Desktop\programas\Nueva carpeta (71)\Proyecto\Proyecto\bin\Debug\7D21.txt'

porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso y solo lo que se necesita es eliminar el archivo, pero no se puede por este tipo de error que me está manejando.

```
public void Apartar(string nameFile) //parametro sera nombre del archivo
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\tApartado de Horarios: ");
        string nombreArchivoLeer = nameFile; //Como hacer para que el usuario ingrese el nombre del archivo??????
        StreamReader leerArchivo = new StreamReader(nombreArchivoLeer);
        string linea = leerArchivo.ReadLine(); //Leo la primera línea
        string[] lineas = new string[100];
        int contador = 0;
        int i ;
        //nombreArchivoLeer = "8D21.txt";
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(nombreArchivoLeer);
            //leo y verifico que no sea null (archivo vacío)

            while ((linea = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lineas[contador] = linea;
                //Console.WriteLine(linea);
                contador++;
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error al leer el archivo: " + e.Message);
        }
        string[] idSala = new string[contador];
        string[] sala = new string[contador];
        string[] dia = new string[contador];
        string[] hora = new string[contador];
        string[] titulo = new string[contador];
        string[] ponente = new string[contador];

        for (i = 0; i < contador; i++)
        {
            //Separar el contenido de la slíneas con split y guardar en el archivo
            string[] datos = lineas[i].Split('|');
            for (int j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                    idSala[i] = datos[j];
                else if (j == 1)
                    sala[i] = datos[j];
                else if (j == 2)
                    dia[i] = datos[j];
                else if (j == 3)
                    hora[i] = datos[j];
                else if (j == 4)
                    titulo[i] = datos[j];
                else if (j == 5)
                    ponente[i] = datos[j];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("idSala: {2}, \tSala:{3}, \tDía: {4}, \tHora: {5}, \tTitulo: {6}, \tPonente: {7}\n",
               i + 1, i, idSala[i], sala[i], dia[i], hora[i], titulo[i], ponente[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("¿Qué horario deseas reservar?: " +
                     "\n1) 9 a 11 am" +
                     "\n2) 11 a 13:00 am" +
                     "\n3) 13 a 2 pm " +
                     "\n4) 2:10 a 3:30 pm " +
                     "\n5) 3:40 a 5 pm" +
                     "\n6) 5 a 7pm");
        int Apartar = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (titulo[Apartar-1] != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre de la ponencia: ");
            string title = Console.ReadLine();
            titulo[Apartar-1] = title;
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del ponente: ");
            string nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            ponente[Apartar-1] = nombre; 
            
            
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EL HORARIO YA ESTA OCUPADO");
        }


        //como escribir los datos de los arreglos en un nuevo archivo
        File.WriteAllText(nameFile, String.Empty);//elimando los archivos
```

El error me lo manda porque no se puede eliminar el archivo en la parte de `File.WriteAllText(nameFile, String.Empty);` por lo que al eliminar este error ya se podrá eliminar el archivo.

Comment: Yo, deja de agregar comillas en los textos, y se mas especifico en las preguntas, y te estaria faltando leer algo de la documentacion y no realizar una pregunta por cada paso que realizas en tu programa.

Comment: Podes usar esta libreria para abrir archivos: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0

Comment: esta muy bien lo que preguntas solo que me falta la  parte de eliminar File.WriteAllText(nameFile, String.Empty);

Comment: `WriteAllText` no cumple la función de borrar archivos si es eso lo que buscas. Mira bien la clase `File`. Tiene una función llamada `Delete`. Esa deberías usar para borrar archivos.

Comment: es muy bueno ya lo probe con Delete y me sigue marcando el mismo error

Comment: me marca el mismo error por mando a llamar el nombre nameFile y este puede agarrar de forma aleatoria los nombres de 3 archivos

Comment: Los saludos no son necesarios, y de hecho, si uno responde a la pregunta _¿es una pregunta muy puntual?_ la respuesta sea _tal vez sí, tal vez no_. Al redactar el título,  tal como te sugiere el _placeholder_, **sé específico**. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Si el proyecto o el archivo que estas intentando eliminar se encuentra en la nube (ya sea Google Drive, OneDrive, etc) no te dejara eliminarlo de esa manera, pues se encuentra alojado en un servidor en la nube.
Deberás moverlo de manera local a tu equipo. Ya sea mover todo tu proyecto a una zona local de tu PC.